# how to use melt to do video overlay? It's just like a PiP(picture in picture)

Tags: overlay, mlt, cross-fade

I want to use melt.exe (command line video editor) to do something with video overlay. It's like overlay a video on the other that I can control the size and position of the video which will be placed. I have done this with shotcut and view the xml it generates. 
But I want to know how can I do this with melt command script. Or if I have known all the information about video overlay such as in/out points, size, position, and how to create a xxx.mlt(xml) file according to these info?

I got the three videos overlaied to generate one like this :
[final effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6gT0.jpg)

I use shotcut to do this and I get a .mlt file. sorry I don't know how to upload the xml file or maybe it can't be.

So I want to know how to do the same thing with melt.exe?

Comment: Your question is very broad and could be considered off-topic. Could you revise your question with the specific problem you are encountering.

Comment: @Benjamin sorry, this is my first time to ask for help on stackflow, and I upload a picture to show what I mean, hope it will helps.